# Relation "schema.table" does not exist exception thrown when using slick 3.3.3

Tags: postgresql, scala, sbt, slick, typesafe

Problem:
So I am trying to connect to a PostgreSql DB with scala slick v3.3.3 and it is failing to find the relation (table) users in schema 'one' within the 'onetest' Database.

I have the following Table setup:

```
CREATE SCHEMA one;
CREATE TABLE one.users (
...
);
```

and the table definition:

```
class UsersTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[UserRequest](tag, Some("one"), "users") {
...
}
```

with database configuration:

```
onedbtest = {
  profile = "slick.jdbc.PostgresProfile$"
  db = {
    dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource" //Simple datasource with no connection pooling. The connection pool has already been specified with HikariCP.
    driver = "slick.driver.PostgresDriver$"
    serverName = "localhost"
    portNumber = "5432"
    databaseName = "onetest"
    user = onetestuser
    password = "password"
    connectionPool = disabled
  }
}
```

and when running (with necessary imports):
`dbConfig.db.run((usersTable += createUserRequest).asTry)`

Why can it not find relations (tables) in db?

Note: Error does not appear (with tests passing) when:
`keepAliveConnection = true` is added to config for DB initialisation however, it writes to another db called "one" (dev environment) doesn't work when `connectionPool = disabled` is added. It should work with the connectionPool attribute added but it doesn't. Strange it is referencing another DB when the db isn't defined anywhere within the code. I am using sbt.version = 1.3.13 and scalaVersion := "2.12.6". `sbt clean compile` and rebuilding does not solve caching issues. I have also killed all processes to stop any open connections and used `db.close` where necessary.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue but to no avail.
It doesn't look like slick has issues with custom schemas.
Rather than bugs in a library behaviour you're describing hints at configuration issues in your project.
There's no way slick can pick up database you haven't configured yourself somewhere within the project.
What may have caused this behaviour is multiple config files that got picked up and merged in a non-deterministic way.

https://github.com/lightbend/config/issues/342

Comment: @tentacle Thanks for your comment, i fixed it. Have a look at the answer :).

Answer (score 1):

I swapped `dataSourceClass = "org.postgresql.ds.PGSimpleDataSource"`
with `dataSourceClass = "slick.jdbc.DatabaseUrlDataSource"`.
This enables the application to actually close collections and not just return connection to connection pool. This in turn allows the application to initialise a new connection to the relevant db and pick up any modifications to the db.